# What is the correct syntax for writing a dynamic timestamp with custom time period in Google BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, dynamic, google-bigquery, timestamp, between

How to write dynamic timestamp with custom time period which change regularly, Tried write the code as below however system throwing error. Please can you suggest correct way of write the syntex

```
select *
FROM
table name
WHERE
  warehouse = "Germany"
  AND pick_open_ts BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), DAY), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
    AND
    TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), DAY), INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
```

Comment: Hi - what are you actually trying to achieve? Please update your question with sample data and the result you want - with an explanation

Comment: what was the error? (in full, don't abbreviate)

Comment: btw: try `pick_open_ts BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL '17 hour') AND (CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL '5 hour')`